# how to develop login using .net web services in android

Tags: android, .net-services

I'm trying to develop login page using .net web services in android because I'm using mssql database so I'm using .net web services but I know that to create login page using wamp server with mysql database in android but I am new in .net web services in android so I need help that how to create login page using .net web services in android.

can any body help me?.

Thanks

Comment: The webservice doesnt really a matter for android. You can use any webservice. When u hit a webservice url. it just returns the corresponding data for the requested parameters.

Comment: but generally we use .net web services for mssql server. but same thing I have done in php(wamp server) with mysql server. I am new in .net web services. please help me.

Comment: You added the tag as android only, for .net add related tags to your question..